# Unable to load .obj files with Helix Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm running into an issue where I can't load 3D `.obj` files into my test app. I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.'

COMException: The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)
```

The code being used is:

```
Model3DGroup combinedModel = new ObjReader().Read(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\obj\testObject.obj");
```

Something odd is that the following works fine for `.stl` files:

```
Model3DGroup combinedModel = new StLReader().Read(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\obj\testObject.stl");
```

I can't find any known issues like this, is there some kind of prerequisite that my system might be missing? Some kind of set up I need to to in the app itself that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this issue appears to occur because of the associated .mtl file that goes with the .obj file.

Moving the material file to a different directory allowed the object file to load properly. The next step will be to figure out why the material file isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What format are the textures referenced by the mtl file? DDS files require a handler to be displayed in WPF. System.Drawing.Design takes care of this for you.